# ROS Fuerte, Gazebo, DAE file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was using my dae files to import into my gazebo. In ROS electric it was working wonderful, but now that I'm working in Fuerte, it's not working anymore.

My configuration is as follows. I added to my *manifest.xml* file  the following lines.

```
 <depend package="gazebo"/>
 <export>
   <gazebo gazebo_media_path="${prefix}" />
 </export>
```

Then I'm using the following file for my model.

**File:** pkg/objects/something.model

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model:physical name="something">
  <xyz>   0      0      0</xyz>
  <rpy>   0.0    0.0    0.0</rpy>
  <static>false</static>
  <body:trimesh name="something_body">
    <massMatrix>true</massMatrix> 
    <mass>1</mass>
    <ixx>0.00</ixx>
    <ixy>0.0</ixy>
    <ixz>0.0</ixz>
    <iyy>0.001</iyy>
    <iyz>0.0</iyz>
    <izz>0.00</izz>
    <cx>0.0</cx>
    <cy>0.0</cy>
    <cz>0.1</cz>
    <geom:trimesh name="something_geom">
      <xyz>0 0 0</xyz>
      <laserRetro>2000.0</laserRetro>
      <kp>1000000.0</kp>
      <kd>1.0</kd>
      <scale>1 1 1</scale>
      <mesh>something.dae</mesh>
      <centerMesh>aabb_bottom</centerMesh>
      <genTexCoord>true</genTexCoord>
      <visual>
        <xyz>0 0 0.0</xyz>
        <scale>1 1 1</scale>
        <material>GazeboWorlds/RGBNoise</material>
        <mesh>something.dae</mesh>
      </visual>
    </geom:trimesh>
  </body:trimesh>
</model:physical>
```

My dae file is in this path **pkg/Media/models/something.dae**.

I'm also using a launch file.

```
<launch>
  <!-- send urdf to param server -->
  <param name="something" textfile="$(find environments)/objects/something.model" />
  <!-- push urdf to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_cube" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-gazebo -param something  -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0 -x -2 -model something" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

And when I don't, I just load it like this:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file objects/something.model -gazebo -model test -z 2
```

Whenever I run the launch file, this is happens.

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[spawn_cube-1]: started with pid [17302]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[spawn_cube2-2]: started with pid [17303]
loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1363095682.076636] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1363095682.142966] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
[spawn_cube-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/8d573604-8b17-11e2-9cb0-0025904ea321/spawn_cube-1*.log
[spawn_cube2-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/8d573604-8b17-11e2-9cb0-0025904ea321/spawn_cube2-2*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

And that's it, it was working perfectly well under ROS electric and it's not working with ROS fuerte. I was trying different approaches, but what it's actually happening, is that it's not taking into account the file. **I even deleted the file and the process always tells that the model has been loaded**. So, what could I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1748/ros-fuerte,-gazebo,-dae-file/) by [silgon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/243/silgon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

If I am not mistaking ROS Fuerte comes with Gazebo version 1.0. Try using [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/beginner/mesh_import) tutorial for importing meshes.

If the model is not found, try copying it to *~/.gazebo/models* folder, or fix the paths.

Spawning from the launch file could also be problematic in that version, try spawning from the .world file. Take a look at [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/854/error-loading-sdf-in-gazebo-131/) answer.

UPDATE:

how to set the paths ([from the install tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.0/install))

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=<install_path>/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/<see above for notes on Ogre>/OGRE-1.7.4" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source <install_path>/share/gazebo-1.0.0/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/243/silgon/) on 2013-03-13**:
The first for the first advice the environment variable GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH didn't exist, so I set it to ~/.gazebo (export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=~/.gazebo, it's not working, for the second advice, I put my model in ~/.gazebo/models, and it didn't work either, I set the GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH variable too. I haven't try the world file as your 3th advice, I think I will be trying it tomorrow, but shouldn't the other files also be working? I mean, since it was working in ROS electric with gazebo.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/243/silgon/) on 2013-03-13**:
I also tried this in my launch file:

And it's not working either

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-13**:
yeah those are all buggy in Gazebo 1.0, either update to a newer version, or spawn them from the .world file, plus don't forget to source the setup.bash file from gazebo folder.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-13**:
I updated the answer, could you confirm what Gazebo version you have, because I am not sure that you have 1.0.